# How to reference on already created object in Realm?

Tags: database, react-native, realm

Let's take example from official realm docs. We have Cars and Persons.

```
const CarSchema = {
  name: 'Car',
  properties: {
    id:  {type: 'string'}, // UUID
    make:  {type: 'string'},
    model: {type: 'string'}
  }
};

const PersonSchema = {
  name: 'Person',
  properties: {
    name:  {type: 'string'},
    car: '' // Something here to reference on already created car??
  }
};
```

For example I already created some cars with UUID id-s. Now I want to create a user. In UI it will look like form, where you write user name and pick from dropdown one of the already created vehicles.

So how to reference on already created car? It should be string with id, or what?

Comment: Shouldn't it be`{type: 'CarSchema'},` ?

Comment: @Divers ok, and then how should create a person and what should be a value of `car` ?

Comment: I don't know how it will be in JS, but in Java should be something like that: `CarSchema car = new CarSchema(12313, "Volvo", "XC60"); PersonSchema person = new PersonSchema("Belarussian", car);` It for cases when there is a proper constructors.

Comment: @Divers Looks like I got you. Thanks, I will try one way :)

Comment: @Divers in your example if I will change car, is it will be also changed in Person object? For example I've change "Volvo" to "VOLVO", It will affect all persons?

Comment: Try to understand what object is and read Realm docs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Links are first-class citizen in Realm, so that you don't need to introduce an artificial foreign-key. You can just link to another object schema directly. In the JavaScript-based bindings, you achieve that by specifying the name of the related object schema as `type` as seen below.

```
const PersonSchema = {
  name: 'Person',
  properties: {
    name:  { type: 'string' },
    car:   { type: 'Car' } // or just: 'Car'
  }
};
```

With such model you can create `Person` objects with an already existing `Car` attached as seen below:

```
const realm = …
const volvo = realm.objects("Car").filtered("make = $0 AND model = $1", "Volvo", "XC60")[0];
const person = realm.create("Person", {
   name: "Tim",
   car:  volvo,
});
```

Comment: i get this Error: Exception in HostFunction: Attempting to create an object of type 'Produits' with an existing primary key