# How to reflect inheritance in Realm React Native JS?

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm, object-oriented-database

I have the following situation:
There are a Divisions, each consist of List of elements. Those elements can be LineChart, DataTable and etc. I want to find a design solution, where Division can contain DivisionElements, which can be LineChart or DataTable ( there are more elements, but let's talk just about 2 ). While Object-Oriented Database commonly support Inheritance, I do have a feeling Realm does not really support it. It is more based on composition. Here is pseudo data-structure:

```
{
  divisions: [
    {
      divisionTitle: 'Ergebnisplan',
      divisionID: '1',
      divisionComponents: [
        {
          componentType: 'dataTable',
          componentID: '11',
          columnTitles: ['', 'Year 2021', 'Year 2022', 'Year 2023', 'Year 2024'],
          data: {
            rowValues: [
              { 'Ordinary Income': ['141275507', '132018907', '142740563', '149158240'] },
              { 'Ordinary Expenses': ['134067604', '140766430', '158197815', '160843652'] },
            ],
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      divisionTitle: 'Entwicklung und Zusammensetzung der Erträge und Aufwendungen',
      divisionID: '2',
      divisionComponents: [
        {
          componentType: 'lineChart',
          componentID: '21',
          xTitle: 'year',
          yTitle: 'earnings',
          lines: [
            {
              lineLabel: 'income',
              lineColor: 'green',
              interpolation: 'linear',
              data: [
                { year: '2021', earnings: '141275507' },
                { year: '2022', earnings: '132018907' },
                { year: '2023', earnings: '142740563' },
                { year: '2024', earnings: '149158240' },
              ],
            },
            {
              lineLabel: 'expenses',
              lineColor: 'red',
              interpolation: 'linear',
              data: [
                { year: '2021', earnings: '134067604' },
                { year: '2022', earnings: '140766430' },
                { year: '2023', earnings: '158197815' },
                { year: '2024', earnings: '160843652' },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

In my React-Native code Division dynamically ( through switch statements ) creates it's children ( LineChart, DataTable and etc ).

1. I tried to design the solution myself and this is what I came up with:

```
export default class DivisionModel extends Realm.Object {
  static schema = {
    name: 'DivisionModel',
    primaryKey: 'divisionID',
    properties: {
      title: 'string',
      divisionID: 'int',
      components: { type: 'list', objectType: 'DivisionComponentModel' },
    },
  };
}

export default class DivisionComponentModel extends Realm.Object {
  static schema = {
    name: 'DivisionComponentModel',
    primaryKey: 'divisionComponentID',
    properties: {
      divisionID: 'int',
      divisionComponentID: 'int',
      componentID: 'int',
      componentType: 'string',
    },
  };
}

export default class DataTableModel extends Realm.Object {
  static schema = {
    name: 'DataTableModel',
    primaryKey: 'componentID',
    properties: {
      componentID: 'int',
      columnTitles: 'string[]',
      rowTitles: 'string[]',
      numberOfColumns: 'int',
      numberOfRows: 'int',
      rowsData: { type: 'list', objectType: 'DataTableRowModel' },
    },
  };
}

export default class LineChartModel extends Realm.Object {
  static schema = {
    name: 'LineChartModel',
    primaryKey: 'componentID',
    properties: {
      componentID: 'int',
      xTitle: 'string',
      yTitle: 'string',
      height: 'int',
      lines: { type: 'list', objectType: 'LineModel' },
    },
  };
}
```

The problem with this is that I store " foreignKeys " just as properties, because there are no foreign keys in Realm ( only object references https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/model-data/relationships-and-embedded-objects/ ). I first have to create a child ( e.g LineChart ), and then store it's ID in it's "parent" ( DivisionComponent ). With this solution **create,delete,update operations will be slow, but read will be fast**. The schema design also looks a bit strange to me.

2. So I asked chatgpt " Provide example of Inheritance in Realm React Native. E.g I have DivisionModel, which contains DivisionComponents. DivisionComponent could be DataTable or LineChart. ". Here is the response:

```
import Realm from 'realm';

// Schema for DataTable
const DataTableSchema = {
  name: 'DataTable',
  properties: {
    // Properties specific to DataTable
    // ...
  },
};

// Schema for LineChart
const LineChartSchema = {
  name: 'LineChart',
  properties: {
    // Properties specific to LineChart
    // ...
  },
};

// Schema for DivisionComponent (Composition)
const DivisionComponentSchema = {
  name: 'DivisionComponent',
  properties: {
    divisionID: 'int', // Reference to parent Division
    divisionComponentID: 'int',
    componentType: 'string',
    dataTable: 'DataTable?', // Optional reference to DataTable
    lineChart: 'LineChart?', // Optional reference to LineChart
  },
};

// Schema for Division
const DivisionSchema = {
  name: 'Division',
  primaryKey: 'divisionID',
  properties: {
    title: 'string',
    divisionID: 'int',
    components: { type: 'list', objectType: 'DivisionComponent' },
  },
};

// Initialize Realm
const realm = new Realm({ schema: [DataTableSchema, LineChartSchema, DivisionComponentSchema, DivisionSchema] });

// Usage example
realm.write(() => {
  const newDataTable = realm.create('DataTable', { /* properties */ });
  const newLineChart = realm.create('LineChart', { /* properties */ });
  
  const newDivisionComponent = realm.create('DivisionComponent', {
    divisionID: 1,
    divisionComponentID: 1,
    componentType: 'DataTable',
    dataTable: newDataTable,
  });

  const newDivision = realm.create('Division', {
    title: 'Division 1',
    divisionID: 1,
    components: [newDivisionComponent],
  });
});
```

First - can't call it inheritance. Secondly, while DivisionComponent holds actual reference to the " child " - he is holding reference to all possible children, where only one child will actually be set and the rest will be null. When fetching DivisionComponent for the division, I have to check which reference is not null. Currently I have 5 elements which are children of DivisionComponent -> 4 references will be null. **Read will take probably longer as first approach, but still fast. Update,delete,create a bit better than first one.**

3. The last solution that came to my mind is more relational rather than object-oriented. The idea is that parent will not know about it's children. The division will just exist with title and divisionID. DivisionComponent will be removed completely. Elements ( e.g DataTable, LineChart and etc ) will hold reference to the parent ( Division ). Similar to what is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40363017/22369836. With this approach I achieve minimal schema design overhead, actual references and **fast create,write,update operations, but read is slow.** I have to go to every table/object ( LineChart, DataTable... ) and ask " do you belong to this division?". This also does not sound optimal.

I am unhappy with all 3 specified approaches, as all of them have issues.

The question is: For the above described use-case and based on 3 possible approaches, what approach would you suggest and why? The suggestions are not only limited to those 3 approaches I have mentioned. I will be glad to get your own schema design proposals.

Comment: There's a lot to this question and some assumptions and leaps of logic (answer 2) that may not be on point. While Realm works best by referencing other objects, its no problem use foreign keys as well - it's just not a 'built in' thing. Ensuring keys are handled correctly requires a bunch of extra code. Not worth it IMO. Then this create,delete,update operations will be slow, but read will be fast is that from actual testing or is it an assumption? Realm is very fast for reading and writing so perhaps more info there would help.

Comment: Inheritance is a little tricky because in other [SDK's like Swift](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/#model-inheritance) it's supported. From what I understand with React, props and composition appear to be the way to go and this [Composition vs Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55328163/is-inheritance-in-react-components-an-anti-pattern) may be a starting point for more info

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.